# Pop Under on Click for RSS Feed - Javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, popup, anchor

I want to set up the site so when users click on RSS feed links (which I display in part of the site), the feed link appears in a pop under.  It makes sense on the site.  It's something my users want.

What I can't figure out is how to populate the rss links that I'm pulling to get them to open in a pop under.

I've got this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a[href^='http']").attr('target','_blank');
});
```

which does open the link in a new window.  I can add another line like this:

```
     $("a[href^='http']").attr('onClick','openpopup()');
```

but I'm not sure how to craft some javascript that will 1) grab the href from the anchor; 2) replace it with a javascript(void); 3) use that url in something like this:

```
function openpopup() {
window.open("url","","toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,width=1250,height=500,left=250,top=175").blur(); window.focus();}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much of a jQuery guy, but this should work

```
$("a[href^='http']").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the link from opening directly
    // open a pop for the link's url 
    var popup = window.open( this.href , "", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,width=1250,height=500,left=250,top=175" ); 
    popup.blur();
    window.focus();
});
```

Comment: this.href is grabbing the url of the open page, not of the anchor.  Ironically it's opening a copy of the current page in the popunder, and the link in the current window instead of vice versa...

Comment: @user624385: Sorry, that should've been `event.preventDefault()`, not `stopPropagation`. Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qzLtN/

Comment: NICE!!  Because I'm not great at these things I didn't get it to work until I realized I needed the window load function, etc.  For those who easily miss such things, all the above goes inbetween the script tags and between:   //<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){    ...        });
  //]]>              I'm sure that will be obvious to most. THANKS A MILLION!!

Comment: @user624385: Good point - the page has to be loaded before you start looking for links. Feel free to click the checkmark next to my answer, by the way :)