# Can I do this without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, target

I use the following code on my site.  I'm wondering if I need jQuery to do it or if standard javascript can handle the process.

```
      <script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
  $("a[href^='http']").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();              // prevent the link from opening directly
                                                        // open a pop for the link's url 
        var popup = window.open( this.href , "", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,width=340,height=10,left=250,top=175" ); 
        // popup.blur();
        // window.focus();   
    });            });             //]]> 
  </script>
```

It's from this page:  [Pop Under on Click for RSS Feed - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043587/pop-under-on-click-for-rss-feed-javascript)

Comment: jQuery is nothing but JavaScript code.

Comment: Of course standard JS can handle this, but it's more work. I would go with jQuery. Without it, you'll have to loop over `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` and check the href for a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it’s relatively simple: just use `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` and traverse the array you get, seting `onclick` for any elements there that have an `href` attribute with a value that starts with `http`. And make this a function that is called via the `onload` attribute in `<html>` for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<div id="divid" onclick="showpop();">click me</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showpop(){
window.open(arguments);
return false;
}
</script>


document.getElementById(eleID).onClick = function (){
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: for a start the jQuery selector is not a DIV and the selector grabs more than a single element !!!

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to go from unobtrusive JS to inline event handlers just to get rid of jQuery.

Comment: questioner is asking about to do this in javascript

Comment: @amiuhle we can also use the event handler in script tag in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
var hrefs = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i in hrefs) {
   if (hrefs[i].href && hrefs[i].href.match(/^http/)) {
    hrefs[i].onclick = function(){
     var popup = window.open( this.href , "", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,width=340,height=10,left=250,top=175" );
     return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'm assuming that assigning the function to a variable and re-using it would consume less memory. Correct?